# Ruby methods. Switch methods

Tags: ruby, oop

Just wondering why

```
def move
  world_switch(@pos_X += 1, @pos_X -= 1, @pos_Y += 1, @pos_Y -= 1)
end

  def world_switch(do_on_north, do_on_south, do_on_east, do_on_west)
    case @facing # => 'NORTH'
    when 'NORTH'
      puts do_on_north # => 1
      do_on_north
    when 'SOUTH'
      do_on_south
    when 'EAST'
      do_on_east
    when 'WEST'
      do_on_west
    end
  end
```

Calling `world_switch`:

```
robot = Robot.new(0, 0, 'NORTH')
robot.move
puts robot.instance_variable_get("@pos_X") #=> 0
```

results in changing nothing, I would like to increase or decrease `instance variable @pos_X or @pos_Y`

This is my initialize method

```
def initialize(pos_X, pos_Y, facing)
    @pos_X, @pos_Y, @facing = pos_X, pos_Y, facing
  end
```

and that's how I create an instance of the class `robot = Robot.new(0, 0, 'NORTH')`

All help will be appreciated

Comment: How do you call `world_switch`? The one above cannot run. And `world_switch` should not defined like that. Since it accepts only instance variables as parameters, we can omit them all. The `self` can provide access to them.

Comment: 1. It is better to use symbols rather than strings for switches. 2. You code will thrown an error because `world_switch` is called before it is defined.

Comment: updated a question, could you please review

Comment: ok, so what do you want to print? Now I get the output as `1 0`, seems normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation for the current behaviour is as [Chowlett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/93884/chowlett) described, but did you intend for your `@pos_X += 1, @pos_X -= 1` etc in `move` to be blocks of code and then for exactly one of these to be called from `world_switch` depending on which way the robot is facing?

If so, move needs to be declared like this

```
def move
  world_switch(Proc.new { @pos_X += 1 }, Proc.new { @pos_X -= 1 },
    Proc.new { @pos_Y += 1 }, Proc.new { @pos_Y -= 1 })
end
```

and then in `world_switch` you can do something like

```
case @facing # => 'NORTH'
    when 'NORTH'
      do_on_north.call
    when 'SOUTH'
      do_on_south.call
 ...
```

Comment: That would indeed make the current code work. I'm not sure it's the best way of doing it, though; do you really need `world_switch` to be so general that you can pass in what "step NORTH" means?

Comment: @Chowlett Agreed. It does seem overly complicated. Something along the lines of [Matt's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/18601/matt) answer would be a nice, simple solution. It depends on whether the exercise is intended to be an example of a more general point, and also whether the OP is a bit unclear on at what point evaluation takes place when parameter passing.

Answer (score 2):

It does nothing because of the way you call `world_switch`. Ruby will evaluate each of the expressions you're passing as parameters before the call.

So, you call move with (say), `@pos_X` and `@pos_Y` both equal to 0. The Ruby does:

```
@pos_X += 1 # => @pos_X = 1; param 1 will be 1
@pos_X -= 1 # => @pos_X = 0; param 2 will be 0
@pos_Y += 1 # => @pos_Y = 1; param 3 will be 1
@pos_Y -= 1 # => @pos_Y = 0; param 4 will be 0

world_switch(1, 0, 1, 0)
```

Then `world_switch` switches based on `@facing`, and simply returns the value of the appropriate parameter. It doesn't change the instance variables at all.

I'm not sure I explained that all that clearly. Let me know if you need clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Chowlett's and mikej's answers (which nicely explain why your code isn't working). You could try something like this:

```
class Player
  def initialize(position)
    @position = position
  end

  def move(direction)
    case direction
    when :north
      @position[:x] += 1
    when :south
      @position[:x] -= 1
    when :east
      @position[:y] -= 1
    when :west
      @position[:y] += 1
    end
  end
end


player = Player.new({:x => 0, :y => 0})
player.move(:north)
puts player.inspect
# => "#<Player:0x16c7ef8 @position={:x=>1, :y=>0}>"
```